# Create a Firebase user with password and provider

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I managed to successfully create users with a password using the Python Admin SDK, but I want to add Google suport, too. I understand I can have a link to sign in with Google in the app, but then the password is overwritten. I could have an option to merge the password with a Google account using `linkWithCredential`, but then the user still has to use the password at least once.

Using the Admin SDK, I first created a user normally then used the generated UID to re-import the user with Google.com set as a provider. The console shows that the user is able to sign in with password **and** google.com, but the password keeps getting rejected with `ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD` (but `password` is still shown as an option when using `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`).

How can I create a user that can sign in with both their password and Google?

Comment: check if your password has at least 6 characters

Comment: It has 9. And let me add that when I don't add Google as a provider, it works. Also, I don't need to worry about typos because I use a script to create the users